# Procedure which returns several rows conditionally

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a procedure which will return a number as out parameter(let's call it out_parameter_result).
According to this number I need to add rows conditionally.

Pseudocode example(don't mind about conditions):

```
if(bitand(out_parameter_result, 1) = 1)
   result.add(select 1 from dual)
if(bitand(out_parameter_result, 2) = 2)
   result.add(select 2 from dual)
if(bitand(out_parameter_result, 4) = 4)
   result.add(select 4 from dual)
return cursor(or resultset) which will contain 1,2,4.
```

Comment: Define "will not work".  The code you posted has a bunch of syntax errors.  I'm not sure whether you have just never built a stored procedure before and aren't aware of the syntax or whether you've introduced syntax errors trying to simplify the real problem in order to post here.

Comment: Please clarify what you want by providing sample data, test case and sample output. What does the procedure need to due? Add more details to your question so people can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different from original, but works fine in my case.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id IN (
       DECODE(bitand(v_info, 1), 1, 0, 1), 
       DECODE(bitand(v_info, 2), 2, 0, 2), 
       DECODE(bitand(v_info, 4), 4, 0, 3)
```